# kotlin inheritance is not working in a test class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a base class which is having some util methods in Java.
I am trying to inherit that base class in a Kotlin test class.

I am able to inherit and able to use the util methods. But the method never called when I run the test.

Please note that I am running some test which uses Espresso.

This is my base class

```
public class BaseTest {
     @get:Rule
     val mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SplashActivity::class.java)

     protected void login(String username, String password) {
        //some logic here
     }
}
```

my kotlin test class

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class FragmentTest : BaseTest() {
    @get:Rule
    val mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SplashActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        OkHttpClient client = HttpClientManager.getInstance().getOkHttpClient();
        idlingResource = CustomOkHttp3IdlingResource.create("okhttp", client);
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    fun flowTest() {
        login("username","password")
    }

}
```

From the Kotlin test class, the login() method never get called. 
Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: please provide your code otherwise nobody will be able to help you. It is like telling a car mechanic your car isnt starting but you don't show it to him.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `login("username","password")` and when the debugger stops there do steps into (probably alt+shift+F7), what do you see then?

Comment: Strangely, when I put a breakpoint, it never reaches this line

Comment: So the problem is not about inheritance, could you post more code from your test class?

Comment: hey @lelloman , right now I am not doing much in my base class, I don't have a constructor as well.

Comment: not the base class but `FragmentTest`. Also are you sure that `flowTest()` is being run?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is being run, added more code to my FragmentTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause, we shouldn't have same @Rule in both parent and derived class, after removing it from the derived class, it works fine now.

This is my base class

```
public class BaseTest {
     @get:Rule
     val mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SplashActivity::class.java)

     protected void login(String username, String password) {
        //some logic here
     }
}
```

my kotlin test class

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class FragmentTest : BaseTest() {
     //it works once I remove the below rule
     //@get:Rule
    //val mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SplashActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        OkHttpClient client = HttpClientManager.getInstance().getOkHttpClient();
        idlingResource = CustomOkHttp3IdlingResource.create("okhttp", client);
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    fun flowTest() {
        login("username","password")
    }

}
```